# How to block a request in an asynchrounous way inside a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, httpwebrequest, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm working on a minimal dyi ad-blocker in a form of a firefox add-on.
This is a project for my courses, so I need to be quite specific on a solution.
The solution goes like this:

1. Catch every request
2. Stop it for a while
3. Do analysis of the URL (simply checking some aspects of the URL using regex)
4. Do analysis of the response (fetch the response, and again using regex, find certain aspects in the URL's response)
5. Console.log everything
6. Block the request

The issue I'm having is that the browser.webRequest.filterResponseData I'm using to check the URL's response data is asynchronous. I've been playing around with everything, but nothing worked.

This is the current code I have:

Manifest.json file:

```
{
    "description": "Adblock by Morty",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MJ Custom Adblock",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "48": "pen.svg"
    },
    "permissions":[
        "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "background":{
        "scripts": ["blocked_domains.js", "background.js"]
    },
    "browser_specific_settings": {
        "gecko": {
          "strict_min_version": "57.0a1"
        }
    }
}
```

background.js

```
let cancelRequest = false;

function listener(details) {
  //console.log(details.requestId);
  let filter = browser.webRequest.filterResponseData(details.requestId);
  filter.onstart = (event) => {
    console.log("started");
  };
  filter.ondata = (event) => {
    console.log("hi");
    console.log(event.data);
    filter.write(event.data);
  };
  filter.onstop = (event) => {
    console.log("stopped");
    cancelRequest = true;
    filter.disconnect();
  };
  filter.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log("some error happened");
  };
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (cancelRequest) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve({cancel: true});
      }
    }, 500);
  });
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  listener,
  {urls: blocked_domains},
  ["blocking"]
```

The blocked domain array is held inside "blocked_domains.js" as it has around 57000 urls.

I've just started so I haven't implemented the analysis yet, what I'm trying to do now is to only return the cancel after the filter's events have finished.

background.js you're seeing there is the latest iteration of it where I tried to implement a promise that waits for a value to be set to true before returning anything. I chose this solution as I don't care about the speed, all I need is the results, I can wait for 30 minutes if I need to.

The issue with the solution provided above is that if I have that return Promise there, none of the filter's functions work (none of the console logs are logged). If the promise is not there and I don't block the request I get all the needed console logs.

I can clearly see that this is purely the async things happening that are breaking everything, yet I can't find a proper solution to solve this. I've tried returning the {cancel:true} inside filter.onstop, Postponing the returning for a while, runnning the whole
webRequest.onBeforeRequest listener as an async function, nothing worked.

Any ideas or solutions?

Edit: I found out the the filterResponseData never gets initialized.

Comment: As you found out the browser won't start the request until you resolve the returned Promise. You also can't block a request after filterResponseData has received data. I think the only solution would be to use `fetch` do make the request manually but it's obviously bad because it duplicates traffic.

Comment: Would it be possible to maybe change the request's data to nothing after the filterResponseData is finished? Somewhat "fake" that is it blocked, but in reality it went through but gave an empty answer.

Comment: Yes, you can overwrite it with an empty string.